# Regex Syntax - Help

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I need to process a HTML content and replace the IMG SRC value with the actual data. For this I have choose Regular Expressions.

In my first attempt I need to find the IMG tags. For this I am using the following expression:

```
<img.*src.*=\s*".*"
```

Then within the IMG tag I am looking for SRC="..." and replace it with the new SRC value. I am using the following expression to get the SRC:

```
src\s*=\s*".*"\s*
```

The second expression having issues:

For the following text it works:

```
<img alt="3D&quot;&quot;" hspace=
    "3D0" src="3D&quot;cid:TDCJXACLPNZD.hills.jpg&quot;" align=
    "3dbaseline" border="3d0" />
```

But for the following it does not:

```
<img alt="3D&quot;&quot;" hspace="3D0" src=
    "3D&quot;cid:UHYNUEWHVTSH.lilies.jpg&quot;" align="3dbaseline"
    border="3d0" />
```

What happens is the expression returns

```
src="3D&quot;cid:TDCJXACLPNZD.hills.jpg&quot;" align=
    "3dbaseline"
```

It does not return only the src part as expected.

I am using C++ Boost regex library.

Please help me to figure out the problem.

Thanks,
Hilmi.

Comment: What a shame you have chosen regular expressions, which are brittle and *cannot* parse general-purpose HTML. Using a proper HTML parser will make it much more reliable. (But what's the deal with the 3D&quots? It looks like a combination of inappropriate quoted-printable and HTML encoding has mangled this markup before you've even begun trying to read it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first regex doesn't work on your sample text for me.  I usually use this instead, when looking for specific HTML tags:

```
<img[^>]*>
```

Also, try this for your second expression:

```
src\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.*` is a "greedy" match - it will grab as much text as it possibly can while still allowing the regex to match. What you probably want is something like this:

```
src\s*=\s*"[^"]*"\s*
```

which will only match non-doublequote characters inside the src string, and thus not go past the ending doublequote.